# Can't remove contacts from "TO" list and they aren't in my Contacts list in Hotmail

Tags: outlook.com

My Hotmail had been hacked in the past and used to send out spam. Changing the password seems to have stopped it.

I now have about 5 porno sounding contacts that show up when I compose a new email and click the "To" button. They don't show up when I click "Contacts". I can't see any way to delete them.

Does anyone know how to get rid of them?